# Помогите мне с проблемой на dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Я передаю с класса User поля но у меня ошибки вот они:The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'.The getter 'surname' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'surname', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'surname'.
Вот мой код:

```
`import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:my_app/views/screens/chat/user_profile.dart';
import '../../../util/data.dart';
import '../../../util/user.dart';

import 'chat_screen.dart';

class Chats extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chats({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ChatsState createState() => _ChatsState();
}

class _ChatsState extends State<Chats> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<User> filteredUsers = [];
  List<User> selectedParticipants = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, initialIndex: 0, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const backgroundColor = Colors.white;
    const textColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    var chats = <User>[
      User(
        dp: 'https://sun9-7.userapi.com/impg/Gei4WnM729extYbflGqEM7QcNKKmrqGU7M0X1w/wf56PzPkmUQ.jpg?size=736x885&quality=95&sign=62e9e06f29e5c23f748b5de1a9c6d7cd&type=album',
        name: 'Бил',
        surname: 'Ворота',
        groupNumber: '112гр',
        email: 'bilvorota@gmail.com',
        groupImage: '',
        groupName: '',
        participants: null,
      ),
      // ... Other user objects
    ];

    var groups = <User>[
      User(
        dp: 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/impg/2mGwJhbmZBmjOZqFLvSONTHEGA2YZ0qInFhoIQ/6_Qz-HanRHw.jpg?size=736x736&quality=95&sign=38cf53d26826dc001ad87896f2f47e66&type=album',
        name: 'Александр',
        surname: 'Костылев',
        groupNumber: '113гр',
        email: 'simple@gmail.com',
        groupName: '',
        groupImage: '',
        participants: null,
      ),
      // ... Other group objects
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          unselectedLabelColor: textColor,
          isScrollable: false,
          tabs: const <Widget>[
            Tab(
              text: "Сообщение",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Группы",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.separated(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
              itemCount: searchController.text.isEmpty
                  ? chats.length
                  : filteredUsers.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                User user = chats[index];
                return ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage(user.dp),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    '${user.name} ${user.surname}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Номер группы: ${user.groupNumber}',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Почта: ${user.email}',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.chat),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _startChatWithUser(context, user);
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _confirmDeleteUser(context, user);
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(user.dp),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _viewUserProfile(context, user);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListView.separated(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
              itemCount: groups.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                User group = groups[index];
                return Card(
                  // Wrap the ListTile with a Card
                  elevation: 2, // Add elevation for a subtle shadow
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage(group.dp),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      '${group.name} ${group.surname}',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Номер группы: ${group.groupNumber}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Почта: ${group.email}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: textColor),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      // Handle group tap
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _showCreateGroupModal(context, selectedUser);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  User? selectedUser;

  void _startChatWithUser(BuildContext context, User user) {
    setState(() {
      selectedUser = user;
    });

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ChatScreen(user: user),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _viewUserProfile(BuildContext context, User user) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => User_Profile(user: user),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _confirmDeleteUser(BuildContext context, User user) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Удаление пользователя'),
          content: Text(
            'Вы уверены, что хотите удалить чат с ${user.name} ${user.surname}?',
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
              },
              child: const Text('Отмена'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _deleteUser(user);
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
              },
              child: const Text('Удалить'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteUser(User user) {
    setState(() {
      // ignore: list_remove_unrelated_type
      chats.remove(user);
    });
  }

  void _showCreateGroupModal(BuildContext context, User? selectedUser) async {
    final groupNameController = TextEditingController();
    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

    File? groupImage;

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Создать группу',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    final pickedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    );
                    if (pickedImage != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        groupImage = File(pickedImage.path);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: groupImage != null
                            ? FileImage(groupImage!)
                            : selectedUser != null
                                ? NetworkImage(selectedUser.dp)
                                : const AssetImage(
                                    'https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8ee05e46a0e0b08b6f5117c4f0d1ceefcb0cba45eb8a29a6328e44b10a1d40a7/68747470733a2f2f736b696c6c69636f6e732e6465762f69636f6e733f693d64617274',
                                  ) as ImageProvider<Object>,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                TextField(
                  controller: groupNameController,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Название группы'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final groupName = groupNameController.text;

                    if (groupImage != null && groupName.isNotEmpty) {
                      final newGroup = User(
                        dp: '',
                        name: groupName,
                        surname: '',
                        groupNumber: '',
                        email: '',
                        groupImage: groupImage!.path,
                        groupName: groupName,
                        participants: selectedParticipants,
                      );

                      setState(() {
                        groups.add(newGroup as Map<String, dynamic>);
                      });

                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    } else {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            'Пожалуйста, выберите изображение и введите название группы.',
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Создать группу'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _selectParticipants(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Выбрать участников'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _selectParticipants(BuildContext context) async {
    final selectedUsers = await showDialog<List<User>>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Выберите участников'),
          content: SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: chats.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final user = chats[index];
                // ignore: iterable_contains_unrelated_type
                final isSelected = selectedParticipants.contains(user);

                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text('${user.name} ${user.surname}'),
                  value: isSelected,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (value != null) {
                        if (value) {
                          selectedParticipants.add(user as User); // Add user
                        } else {
                          // ignore: list_remove_unrelated_type
                          selectedParticipants.remove(user); // Remove user
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop([]);
              },
              child: const Text('Отмена'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedParticipants);
              },
              child: const Text('Выбрать'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    if (selectedUsers != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedParticipants = selectedUsers;
      });
    }
  }
}
`
```